# Which is better, the atomic's competition between: threads of the single Warp or threads of different Warps?

Tags: cuda, synchronization, gpgpu

Which is better, the atomic's competition (concurrency) between threads of the single Warp or between threads of different Warps in one block? I think that when you access the shared memory is better when threads of one warp are competing with each other is less than the threads of different warps. And with access to global memory on the contrary, it is better that a threads of different warps of one block competed less than the threads of single warp, isn't it?

I need it to know how better to resolve competition (concurrency) and what better to separate store: between threads in single warp or between warps.

Incidentally it may be said that the team __ syncthreads (); synchronizes it warps in a single block and not the threads of one warp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a significant number of threads in a block perform atomic updates to the same value, you will get poor performance since those threads must all be serialized. In such cases, it is usually better to have each thread write its result to a separate location and then, in a separate kernel, process those values.

If each thread in a warp performs an atomic update to the same value, all the threads in the warp perform the update in the same clock cycle, so they must all be serialized at the point of the atomic update. This probably means that the warp is scheduled 32 times to get all the threads serviced (very bad).

On the other hand, if a single thread in each warp in a block performs an atomic update to the same value, the impact will be lower because the pairs of warps (the two warps processed at each clock by the two warp schedulers) are offset in time (by one clock cycle), as they move through the processing pipelines. So you end up with only two atomic updates (one from each of the two warps), getting issued within one cycle and needing to immediately be serialized.

So, in the second case, the situation is better, but still problematic. The reason is that, depending on where the shared value is, you can still get serialization between SMs, and this can be very slow since each thread may have to wait for updates to go all the way out to global memory, or at least to L2, and then back. It may be possible to refactor the algorithm in such a way that threads within a block perform atomic updates to a value in shared memory (L1), and then have one thread in each block perform an atomic update to a value in global memory (L2).

The atomic operations can be complete lifesavers but they tend to be overused by people new to CUDA. It is often better to use a separate step with a parallel reduction or parallel stream compaction algorithm (see `thrust::copy_if`).